# RealmRecyclerViewAdapter 2.0.0 autoUpdate

Tags: realm

I don't want to [Added fine grained notification support to RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.] How to do it ?

I used onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, int position)

position --- > Serial number

not work.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking?

Comment: I think you can  choose to use previous version, that calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` meaning no animations

Comment: 2.0 can't no animations ?